# Exporting DOC to PDF using POI

Tags: .net, apache-poi, office-interop, npoi

In our project in .NET (executed on a WS exposed on our Intranet Server) we wanted to do somethings with existing doc and docx documents, without office installed on the server of course :

- accept all the pending changes in the doc (just like in the "accept all changes in the revision ribbon")
- export to PDF (or images at worst-case scenario)

After spending our to check if these features are available on NPOI (the .net version of the project POI), I was unable to verify it. It doesn't seems to be a very often occurring case !!

Can anyone confirm me (or not) if it is possible?

Comment: I used OpenOffice/LibreOffice for exporting to PDF, it has some automation-support, i.e. something like `unoconv -vvv --timeout=10 --doctype=document --output=result.pdf result.docx` will convert the doc to pdf.

Comment: @centic Ok, do you have a good rendering accuracy with uno ? We have Word dopcument with charts, grouped or ungoruped shapes, images... I think i will give a try anyway. Do you know if it is working with a 'portable' version of Open/Libre Office ?

Comment: It was good enough for some simple use-cases for me and I would expect it to be fairly good at rendering everything that LibreOffice can display/work with. Basically the export does the same thing as if you do a "Save as.../Export" to PDF in normal LibreOffice/OpenOffice, so you should be able to give it a try quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: No, currently (N)POI does not offer any functionality to export a PDF file. The library focuses on manipulating Microsoft Office documents directly, not on converting them to different formats.

There are a lot of other libraries and services out there that will solve this (I can personally recommend *Aspose.Words*, but it should definitely be possible to find something cheaper out there that meets your requirements).